# Matlab script to rename signal name

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have simulink block which has thousands of input signal for example which contains a text TRXA

```
AIM1_Freshness_TRXA_FCC,
AIM2_Freshness_TRXA_FCC
```

I need to create exact replica of the model only change is TRXA is changed to TRXB

```
AIM1_Freshness_TRXB_FCC ,
 AIM2_Freshness_TRXB_FCC
```

Any easy or matlab script to do that

Comment: Looks more like a job for sed, Python, Perl or any other language with better textprocessing capabilities. Don't use a hammer to drive a screw.

Comment: Matlab supports regular expressions in some of its commands, which could be applicable in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the following help?

```
open_system('your_model')
x = find_system('RegExp','on','FindAll','on','Name','TRXA');
for idx=1:size(x,1)
    name_orig = get_param(x(idx),'Name');
    set_param(x(idx),'Name',strrep(name_orig,'TRXA','TRXB'));
end
```